# html field for a blog content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making my own blog with ruby on rails. But when I create a field for the content in the form, I can only show plain text. How can I show an html text from my field content.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In controller:
@some_variable = "<p>Hi there</p>"

In the view:
<%= @some_variable.html_safe %>
```

html_safe tells rails that your string is ok to display without escaping it first.

Comment: NP, but be sure you don't let people you don't trust put html into that variable! Because that is a Bad Idea.